# c# one to many string parsing help using regex lambda

Tags: c#, regex, linq, parsing, lambda

I know how to do this using the obvious way with string.split().

I am looking for a more elegant and faster performing code possibly using regex and/or linq/lambdas.

If my input string is like this "GradeId1:StudentName1*StudentName2*...StudentNameN,GradeId2:StudentName1*StudentName2....StudentNameN,....GradeN:Student1*StudentName2*...StudentNameN"

Gist: One contiguous string of Grades and students. GradeId is int , student name is string.
Grades separated by comma and student name separated by star.

It is possible there are no students in a particular grade as in
"1:stud1*stud2*stud3,2,3" Here grades 2 and 3 have no students. Only grade 1 has 3 students.
My objective is to get a collection where I could

```
foreach(Grade g in mycollection)
{ 
  foreach (int i = 0; i < g.studentnames.length; i++)
     console.writeline( g.StudentNames[i] ) 
}

class Grade { int gradeid, string[] studentnames }
```

regex and linq Gurus, please advise. thank you

Comment: I don't see any place for grades to fit in your example.  It looks like it's just a Grade ID and student names.

Comment: I think he's inferring that the grade id is the grade, possibly a primary key into a domain table?

Comment: Could also do it quick and dirty with a string split...

Comment: According to your example there are multiple student names per grade, but in your code you are printing single student names.

Comment: Guys , i have updated the original question and made it more clear. thanks

Comment: All, agent-j below has a solution that uses regex to do the task needed. What are your thoughts on this ? Which of the solutions posted here is the fastest ? The one that uses regex or the other 2 that do not use regex. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data format is the way you described it, this maybe what you're looking for? You still should probably use the String.Split() to work with the input as it's a string delimited list, but you can at least make it an anonymous typed collection.

```
string input = "10:name1*20:name2*30:name3*40:name4*50:name5";

var data =
(
    from pair in input.Split( '*' )
    let student = pair.Split( ':' )
    select new { Grade = int.Parse( student[ 0 ] ), Name = student[ 1 ] }
);

foreach( var student in data )
{
    Console.WriteLine( student );
}
```

Edit:

It seems you have a 1:many grade -> student relationship? Maybe you should look into using a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) collection to get all the students with N grade easily.

```
string input = "10:name1.1*name1.2*name1.3,20:name2.1*name2.2*,30:name3.1,40:name4.1*name4.2*name4.3,50:name5.1";

var studentData = ( Lookup<int,string[]> )
(
    from 
        line in input.Split( ',' )
    where 
        line.IndexOf( ':' ) > -1
    let 
        grade = line.Substring( 0, line.IndexOf( ':' ) )
    let 
        names = line.Remove( 0, grade.Length + 1 ).Split( '*' )
    select 
        new { Grade = int.Parse( grade ), Students = names }
).ToLookup( s => s.Grade, s => s.Students );

foreach( IGrouping<int,string[]> gradeSet in studentData )
{
    Console.WriteLine( gradeSet.Key );
    Console.WriteLine( studentData[ gradeSet.Key ] );
}
```

Also, I realize this isn't the "linqy-est" solution, but hopefully it'll make your job easier.

Comment: thanks Brandon. Will wait for one or two days and see what other Guru's have to say. Otherwise I plan to use your solution.

Comment: I have updated my question since there was some confusion. Please update your solution if needed. thanks

Comment: I am no rookie but never used the lookup collection before. Something new to learn with .net everyday. As someone said .net has put the fun back in coding. Iam old school 45 years old c/unix coder that has moved to c#. thanks

Comment: Your solution fails when we have no students in any grade on this line " names = line.Remove( 0, grade.Length + 1 ).Split( '*' )
" The input in this case is "string input = "10:name1.1*name1.2*name1.3,20,30" Notice grade 20 and 30 have no students. pls update your code when you get a chance. thanks

Comment: @User I fixed that bug, but please don't use this in like a "production" application. I threw that crap together in like 2 minutes.

Comment: There is no error now but it does not spit out the grade id with no students. The input in this case is "string input = "10:name1.1*name1.2*name1.3,20,30" Notice grade 20 and 30 have no students. It does not print 20 and 30. Only 10 is printed to console.

Answer (score 2):

OpticalDelusion is right that Linq will definitely HURT performance.  In general, Linq is convenient, but not fast.

Regex isn't useful for the actual parsing in complex string splitting cases like this - it's more useful for finding a particlar pattern in an arbitrary string or whitelisting the string.  So if you wanted to make sure that the input string is in the correct format, you could use a regex pattern like this:

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\*[a-zA-Z0-9])*)(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\*[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"
```

Basically, any character or number, one or more times, followed by a colon, then another sequence of letters or numbers and then a '*' and another sequence of letters or numbers 0 or more times.  This is then repeated 0 or more times.

Once you've ensured the string is in the proper format, you can do string.split() operations.

Comment: Hold on before you use this, I think I just found a bug in the matching string.  I'll edit as soon as I get out of a meeting

Comment: thanks for that tip. ie., Regex for ensuring string is in correct format and not really for parsing. In my case the string is in the right format and I do not need to check the grammar. So my solution will be the obvious string.split() way. I just need to pick the most elegant way now from all the posts.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Now using the OP's new input string.

```
string mystring = "GradeId1:StudentName1*StudentName2*StudentNameN,GradeId2:StudentName1*StudentName2*StudentNameN,GradeIdN:Student1*StudentName2*StudentNameN";
MatchCollection matches = 
   Regex.Matches(
      mystring,
      @"(?:GradeId(\w+)(?:(?=,)|\:(?:([\w ]+)(?:$|\*))*))");

var grades = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(
   gradeMatch => 
      new
      {
         Grade = gradeMatch.Groups[1].Value,
         Students = gradeMatch.Groups[2].Captures
            .Cast<Capture> ()
            .Select (c => c.Value).ToList ()
      });

foreach (var grade in grades)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Grade: " + grade.Grade);
   foreach (string student in grade.Students)
      Console.WriteLine("   " + student);
}
```

For this string, `GradeId1:StudentName1*StudentName2*StudentNameN,GradeId2,GradeIdN:Student1*StudentName2*StudentNameN` produces this output:

```
Grade: 1
   StudentName1
   StudentName2
Grade: 2
Grade: N
   Student1
   StudentName2
   StudentNameN
```

For the interested:

```
match[0].Value => GradeId1:StudentName1*StudentName2*
match[0].Groups[0].Value => GradeId1:StudentName1*StudentName2*
match[0].Groups[0].Captures[0].Value => GradeId1:StudentName1*StudentName2*
match[0].Groups[1].Value => 1
match[0].Groups[1].Captures[0].Value => 1
match[0].Groups[2].Value => StudentName2
match[0].Groups[2].Captures[0].Value => StudentName1
match[0].Groups[2].Captures[1].Value => StudentName2
match[1].Value => GradeId2
match[1].Groups[0].Value => GradeId2
match[1].Groups[0].Captures[0].Value => GradeId2
match[1].Groups[1].Value => 2
match[1].Groups[1].Captures[0].Value => 2
match[1].Groups[2].Value =>
match[2].Value => GradeIdN:Student1*StudentName2*StudentNameN
match[2].Groups[0].Value => GradeIdN:Student1*StudentName2*StudentNameN
match[2].Groups[0].Captures[0].Value => GradeIdN:Student1*StudentName2*StudentNameN
match[2].Groups[1].Value => N
match[2].Groups[1].Captures[0].Value => N
match[2].Groups[2].Value => StudentNameN
match[2].Groups[2].Captures[0].Value => Student1
match[2].Groups[2].Captures[1].Value => StudentName2
match[2].Groups[2].Captures[2].Value => StudentNameN
```

Comment: Wow. thanks. Looks really cool and will take me some time to digest. But if this is faster than some of the other suggested solutions I am willing to swallow.

Comment: Does not print GradeId2 when the input is string mystring = "GradeId1:StudentName1*StudentName2*StudentNameN,GradeId2,GradeIdN:Student1*StudentName2*StudentNameN"; Basically GradeId2 has no students. Pls update your code. There is no runtime or compile time error unlike Brandon's solution. thanks

Comment: @user666490, check out the new expression and results.

Comment: works like a champ and iam in awe of your regex and linq skills. However there is a perception after reading other posts and articles online that the split approach taken by Brandon and Somedave here is faster since it splits by the required delimiter (there is no searching for a regex "pattern" to get a collection of matches first, then operate on this pattern matched collection.), Pls let me know your thoughts on this. thanks

Comment: I would venture a guess that whatever is more readable and maintainable is better in this case.  If you have a huge number of students (like a thousand or more) per grade, I believe the regex could be better/faster if you consider the cost of allocating and garbage-collecting the extra per-grade strings.  Truthfully, the regex was such a pain to write, I don't think I would use it if I had another easy option.  HA HA. I'd settle for an upvote, though.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer using one (long) line of Linq (I prefer to use the extension methods directly, but you could use the short Linq syntax too). I'm not sure using Linq/extensions is more "elegant" or any simpler than doing it long-hand with nested ifs and the like. I will admit, there's something cool about a nice long Linq expression that gets a complex job done.

```
string input = "1:A*B*C,2:A*B,3:B*C*D";
var grades = input
  .Split(',')
  .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
  .Select(x => x[1].Split('*').Select(n => new { GradeId = x[0], StudentName = n }))
  .SelectMany(x => x)
  .ToList();
```

This produes a `List<T>` of anonymous types with GradeId and StudentName fields for all combinations.

Edit: The revised question is a little easier. Here's how you could get the nested lists as requested using this technique:

```
var grades = input
  .Split(',')
  .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
  .Select(x => new { GradeId = x[0], StudentNames = x[1].Split('*').ToList() })
  .ToList();
```

You can then iterate like so:

```
foreach(var grade in grades)
{
  //You could always use a foreach here too
  for(int i = 0; i < grade.StudentNames.Length ; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(grade.StudentNames[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is designed to support input strings with the complex one-to-many GradeId to StudentName relationship as indicated in the question. If the format of the input only contains one GradeId for every StudentName, then some of the other answers are more appropriate.

Comment: thanks somedave.Right now we have 3 solutions. (one uses lookup/Igrouping , the other uses regex and yours is the most vanilla of the 3. I am having a hard time picking since I dont know which one is the fastest. Dont have time to put performance counters etc. Maybe someone will step in and tell me which solution is the fastest.

Comment: Pls update your code to handle no students in any particular grade as in string input = "1:A*B*C,2,3:B*C*D"; where Grade 2 has no students. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do Linq and lambda stuff like this but I don't think you will see a positive performance difference and it will be more code than if you just parsed it normally.

```
var grades = (from s in text select s).TakeWhile(a => !a.Equals(','));
```

Sorry I am not about to do the whole thing for you unless you really need help and really want to do it this way.

Comment: thanks. please post the whole code like Brandon has done below. It is not much as you know. Iam not expert at linq/lambdas yet and it will help. But if it will not be faster than Brandon's code below do not bother.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, String.Split() tends to be the best option in most cases where it's workable.  The one exception is when you're dealing with very large blocks of text that can't be read one line at a time (or similar) so that that attacking it with Split() will end up cramming the heap full of large string arrays.

In those cases you could produce a composition of enumerator blocks.  The inside of them might be a loop that uses String.IndexOf() to find successive delimiters, and then uses Substring() to yank out and yield the text between them.  It helps to limit the number of strings that are on the heap at any one time, but stops short of treating a string as IEnumerable (which doesn't tend to perform as well in my experience).

For that matter, it might be fine to just use one block like that, and revert back to using String.Split() for handling its results.

Comment: thx. I was inclined to just use split and do it the old fashioned way but Iam glad I asked here for advise since I learned so many new things as you can see from the solutions posted here. The dish must taste good and should also be presented nicely. I mean code performance and elegance.